# Div animation starting from translateX 100% starting from 0% on mobile

Tags: css, css-transforms

While animating a page transition I noticed a weird behavior.

On mobile... when I start a page from `translate(%100,0);` it starts from its beginning position and animates out of view to the left instead of starting from outside of view to the left... and animating to the center of view.

You can see the issue live at dbz-test.myshopify.com.

The animation works perfectly on desktop... but try it from your phone.

Comment: click the cart icon......then click the logo ....and you will see the transition issue

Comment: just noticed that it works if i remove and re-add the page div that im animating to the dom...